# Locating a printer in a print (as in full path) via its IP address

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a question
I want to create a script which locates a tcp/ip printer in the print servers so it could be "properly" installed, right now the solution we have is to go through the print servers and sort via description (where the ip is listed for each printer) and look manually, I want to automate this process.
Problem is, I can't use dir on the print server (won't let me idk exactly why)

Anyone got an idea?

So far I've made a script which locates all the network printers (let it be TCP/IP or installed via print servers) on a remote computer via querying the remote pc's registry, but I got stuck on this one.

BTW, it must be in batch, as I cannot use Powershell effectifly as part of my job (as Help desk)

Tried using dir and it throws as error because it's a network path.
Tried using (reverse) nslookup, but the printers don't have DNS records.

So far this is the (relevant) code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p pc=Enter Computer Name or IP address:
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('reg query "\\%pc%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers" 2^> nul ') do (
   for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "\\%pc%\%%i" /v Port 2^> nul') do (
      set "port=%%b"
      set "check=!port:.=!"
      if not "!port!"=="!check!" (
         echo !port!
      )
   )
)
pause
```

which will output the IP address of the printer, like so
`122.1.21.1`
And then I want to check for the printer's full path in several possible print servers

```
set "svrs=\\pr1 \\pr2 \\pr3 etc.."
::code here, which I'm not sure how to do it
if %port% == %printer_description% (
  echo %port% is at %full_path%
  goto continue_with_code
) 
pause
```

Which should hopefully output
`\\print_server\printer_name`
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Show us your code! Edit it into your post by using the `edit` button. Select the code and press the `{}` button to format. Show us a representative listing of the result. Obfuscate any sensitive info by replacing `Sensitive 123` with `Abcdefghi 987` - replace with like-for-like characters (alpha/numeric/case/spaces/special characters and length). This should give us appropriate data to devise a solution.

Comment: Fine - now please show a sample of **YOUR** result listing as others will not be dealing with the same data. Especially include any instances of lines that contain spaces or other symbols.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that tbh. The output of this script will be IP address of the printer, which I want to convert to full path of the printer in the print server. Sample output ```123.1.2.3```, sample desired full path ```\\pr1\random_printer```

Comment: On my system your code delivers `ECHO is off. ECHO is off. ECHO is off.`

Comment: I did, sorry for the confusion, first time posting here. Thanks for clarifying!, weird, ```ECHO is off``` wouldn't mean that vars aren't defined or empty? I specifically used delayed expansion to prevent it and it does work on my end... Welp. I kinda put this thing together, I didn't study batch, I studied python so I'm not very "good" at batch